# Run code after asyncio run_until_complete() statement has finished

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, synchronous, aiohttp

I am fairly new to `asyncio` and I managed to do some requests with it. I made a function `fetch_all()` that takes in a list of the queries (URLs) and the loop previously created with `asyncio` as arguments, and calls the function `fetch()` that gets the result of each query in JSON format:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import ssl
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, ssl=ssl.SSLContext()) as response:
        return await response.json()

async def fetch_all(urls, loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(*[fetch(session, url) for url in urls], return_exceptions=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(queries, loop))
```

This works properly, and I get the results of the queries in `results` as a list of JSONs (dictionaries). But here goes my problem: sometimes, instead of the JSON, I get an error for some results (`RuntimeError`, `aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError`, etc.). I guess these are one-time errors, since if I redo the query individually I get the desired result. Hence, I came up with a `while` loop to check which results are not dictionaries and redo their queries: I initialize `repeat_queries`, `error_index` and `results` with the queries and their indices, and apply `run_until_complete()`. Then I save each result that is a dictionary and update the list of the queries that are left and their indices:

```
repeat_queries = queries
error_index = list(range(len(repeat_queries)))
results = error_index

while error_index:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        repeat_results = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(repeat_queries, loop))
    for i, rr in zip(error_index, repeat_results):
        results[i] = rr
    error_index = [i for i in range(len(results)) if not isinstance(results[i], dict)]
    repeat_queries = [repeat_queries[i] for i in error_index]
```

However, since the `asyncio` loop is asynchronous, `error_index` and `repeat_queries` updates are executed before `run_until_complete()` is done, and the loop is continuously running with queries that were already cast in the previous iterations, resulting in an (almost) infinite `while` loop.

**Therefore, my question is:**
Is there any way to force some code to be executed after `loop.run_until_complete()` has finished?
I have seen some similar questions in stackoverflow but I haven't been able to apply any of their answers.

Comment: I think you overcomplicted some code - you could use `for i, rr, enumerate(repeat_results)`  instead of using `list(range(len(repeat_queries)))` . And you could do all in one `for`-loop instead of using one `for`-loop to create `results[i], other `for`-loop to create `errorn_index`, and third `for`-loop to get `repeat_queries`.

Comment: you should run all code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: I would use `while`-loop inside `fetch()` to repeate it at once - not wait for end of all data. Eventually I would use loop `for _ in range(3): ... break` to repeat it only 3 times - if there is problem - and use `break` if it get correct data.

Comment: if you saw similar questions then you could add links in question (not in comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in different way.

I would run loop inside `fetch()` with `try/except` to catch exception and repeate it.

Because some problems can never give result so `while`-loop may run forever - so I would rather use `for _ in range(3)` to try it only three times.

I would also return `url` from `fetch` so it would be easer to get urls which don't give result.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import ssl

async def fetch(session, url):
    exception = None
    
    for number in range(3):  # try only 3 times
        try:
            async with session.get(url, ssl=ssl.SSLContext()) as response:
                data = await response.json()
                #print('data:', data)
                return url, data
        except Exception as ex:
            print('[ERROR] {} | {} | {}'.format(url, number+1, ex))
            exception = ex
            
    return url, exception

async def fetch_all(urls, loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(*[fetch(session, url) for url in urls], return_exceptions=True)


queries = [
    'https://httpbin.org/get',
    'https://toscrape.com',
    'https://fake.domain/'
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(queries, loop))

    #print(results)
    
    print('--- results ---')
    
    for url, result in results:
        print('url:', url)
        print('result:', result)
        print('is dict:', isinstance(result, dict))
        print('type:', type(result))
        print('---')
```

Result:

```
[ERROR] https://fake.domain/ | 1 | Cannot connect to host fake.domain:443 ssl:<ssl.SSLContext object at 0x7f3902afc2c0> [Name or service not known]
[ERROR] https://fake.domain/ | 2 | Cannot connect to host fake.domain:443 ssl:<ssl.SSLContext object at 0x7f3902afc440> [Name or service not known]
[ERROR] https://fake.domain/ | 3 | Cannot connect to host fake.domain:443 ssl:<ssl.SSLContext object at 0x7f3902afc9c0> [Name or service not known]
[ERROR] https://toscrape.com | 1 | 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html', url=URL('https://toscrape.com')
[ERROR] https://toscrape.com | 2 | 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html', url=URL('https://toscrape.com')
[ERROR] https://toscrape.com | 3 | 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html', url=URL('https://toscrape.com')
--- results ---
url: https://httpbin.org/get
result: {'args': {}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'Python/3.8 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-60e5c00e-45aae85e78277e5122b262c9'}, 'origin': '83.11.175.159', 'url': 'https://httpbin.org/get'}
is dict: True
type: <class 'dict'>
---
url: https://toscrape.com
result: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html', url=URL('https://toscrape.com')
is dict: False
type: <class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ContentTypeError'>
---
url: https://fake.domain/
result: Cannot connect to host fake.domain:443 ssl:<ssl.SSLContext object at 0x7f3902afc9c0> [Name or service not known]
is dict: False
type: <class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError'>
---
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which uses your method with looping `run_until_complete` but I would do all in one `for`-loop.

And I would use `for _ in range(3)` to repeate it only three times.

This works but previous version seems much simpler.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import ssl

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, ssl=ssl.SSLContext()) as response:
        return await response.json()

async def fetch_all(urls, loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(*[fetch(session, url) for url in urls], return_exceptions=True)

queries = [
    'https://httpbin.org/get',
    'https://httpbin.org/json',
    'https://toscrape.com',
    'https://fake.domain/'
]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # you can get it once
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # original all queries
    all_queries = queries
    # places for all results  
    all_results = [None] * len(all_queries)
    
    # selected indexes at start
    indexes = list(range(len(all_queries)))
        
    for number in range(3):
        # selected queries
        queries = [all_queries[idx] for idx in indexes]
        
        # selected results
        results = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(queries, loop))
        
        print('\n--- try:', number+1, '--- results:', len(results), '---\n')
        
        new_indexes = []
        
        for idx, url, result in zip(indexes, queries, results):
            all_results[idx] = result
            if not isinstance(result, dict):
                new_indexes.append(idx)

            print('url:', url)
            print('result:', result)    
            print('is dict:', isinstance(result, dict))
            print('type:', type(result))
            print('---')
                
        # selected indexes after fitering correct results
        indexes = new_indexes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your tips and your answer! I tried your solution and 3 times in the ```for``` loop seem enough, I am getting all the results properly

Comment: you could make it more universal and add it as paramater - `fetch(session, url, tries=3):` and `for number in range(tries)` - so you could run it with different values.